# How can I get the max value of a y axis at highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I get the max value of a y axis at highcharts?

i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-basic/ here max value is **30**. If you disable New York and Tokyo it is **20** and so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming that `chart` is your chart var.
`chart.yAxis[0].max;`

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/m7gV5/)

**Update**

@Anagio told that it's possible to get it the following way.
`chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes`

This way you can get the data values and the tick values.
The data values are the values from your series, while the tick values are the values from chart lines.

[**Reference**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes)

Comment: It shows the previous value? Also not showing anything at first time, before chart is rendering?

Comment: @kamaci For the fist time you have to use the event `load` whith `this` instead of `chart`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m7gV5/1/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think I need sth. like beforeLoad and beforeRedraw. On the other hand I want this to update the units of y axis.(i.e. unit will be GB and if user disable some series I will change it to bytes, TB or etc.) I don't know if I am on the right way but I should call formatter function of y axis. Can I do it within load and redraw methods?

Comment: @kamaci Yeap, `load` will be called once, `redraw` will be called everytime it get's redraw, so make a function and use both.

Comment: I am accepting it as an answer and I will ask it as a new question.

Comment: I asked a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308643/how-can-i-change-the-unit-at-y-axis-dynamically-at-highcharts

Comment: @kamaci Highcharts has a function to give you the maximum value of an Axis http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes this gives you the extreme values of an axis, which is more accurate because using the method in this answer may return the calculated max tick value.

Comment: @Anagio what do you mean with "tick value"?

Comment: @kamaci Highcharts may calculate a number higher than the largest value in your data series. For example if I have a number in my data series of 590, the top grid line and label mark / tick in the yAxis at the top of the chart could be 700 800 or even 1000. Which is the number returned use `.max` which is why the function I linked to above is better the `getExtrems()` function returns the highest value within your data in a series.

Answer (score 12):

This information is directly accessible from a `Axis` object. For example:

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
var axisMax = chart.yAxis[0].max; // Max of the axis
var dataMax = chart.yAxis[0].dataMax; // Max of the data
```

As mentioned you can use `Axis.getExtremes` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes)) , but the same data is also available as:

- `Axis.min`: Min of the axis
- `Axis.max`: Max of the axis
- `Axis.dataMin`: Min of the data
- `Axis.dataMax`: Max of the data

And even some historic data if the extremes of the axis has changed:

- `Axis.oldMin`: The previous min of the axis
- `Axis.oldMax`: The previous max of the axis

Comment: In typescript, getExtremes matched the highcharts typings for what was available on the yAxis object, that seems to be the way to go-