# How can I change the unit at y axis dynamically at Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How can I change the unit at y axis dynamically at Highcharts?

I have a formatter for y axis:

```
 yAxis:{
        title:{
            text:'Custom Title'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                var maxElement;//I want to set it to max value at y axis labels

                if(maxElement > gb){
                    return (this.value / gb).toFixed(1) + " GB";
                }else if(maxElement > mb){
                    return (this.value / mb).toFixed(1) + " MB";
                }else if(maxElement > kb){
                    return (this.value / kb).toFixed(1) + " KB";
                } else {
                    return (this.value) + " B";
                }
            }
        },
      ...
```

I asked a question here: [How can I get the max value of a y axis at highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301236/how-can-i-get-the-max-value-of-a-y-axis-at-highcharts) about how to get the max value at y axis labels. However I think I should have sth like beforeLoad and beforeRedraw methods.

How can I change dynamically units of y axis labels (because if you disable/close series at right side max y axis label changes)?

Other solutions about my problem is welcome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This case you can get the `max` by the following line:
`this.axis.max;`

So your function should be:

```
formatter: function() {
    var maxElement = this.axis.max;
    if (maxElement > gb) {
        return (this.value / gb).toFixed(1) + " GB";
    } else if (maxElement > mb) {
        return (this.value / mb).toFixed(1) + " MB";
    } else if (maxElement > kb) {
        return (this.value / kb).toFixed(1) + " KB";
    } else {
        return (this.value) + " B";
    }
}​
```

You can see it **[working here](http://jsfiddle.net/RFcPD/)**.

Comment: That is what I am exactly looking for. Did you find it Highcharts API?

Comment: @kamaci you may not be able to get the entire object graph's info in the api reference, but the browsers DOM inspector or a debugging tool like firebug or the inbuilt ones surely come handy when you wish to see the list of available properties of a given object

Comment: I debugged yAxis object but I didn't think to debug axis element. I should find the way how to find what I need.

Comment: How did you decided these values?

kb = 19,
mb = 29,
gb = 39;

Comment: @Vishal, It is just an example. There is no logic for that decision but just to show how OP's question can be addressed.