# How can I get the top value of the yAxis labels in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Let say we have this set of data:

```
var data = [10, 20, 15, 40, 30, 25];
```

With highcharts, the maximum value of the yAxis would be 50 or something. Here's the basic example from their site: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/

My question is. How can I get the number 50 (in my case) and number 250 in their example in a javascript variable so I can write logic based on that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the max value of a y axis at highcharts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301236/how-can-i-get-the-max-value-of-a-y-axis-at-highcharts)

Comment: answer is the same, question is different. My goal was to get the max value of the axis, without any regard to the values set in the chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12301683/691148)

Assuming that `chart` is your chart var.

`chart.yAxis[0].max;`

In addition to that the same works for the x axis:

`chart.xAxis[0].max;`

If the x axis is a collection of elements (for example month names) it outputs the number of elements - 1.

Comment: The documentation says that's the maximum value to set for the chart. I thought it was a user setting that will force data to render with a top limit. Thanks :)

Comment: You can indeed do that as well.