# Get max of x axis in highcharts using react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to get the [max value of the x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301236/how-can-i-get-the-max-value-of-a-y-axis-at-highcharts) and set an annotation just at the end:

```
y: chart.xAxis[0].max-1
```

What is the right syntax to get it working in react? See a live demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ox91q21xj5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use values from the chart in options. You should add your annotations dynamically in `addAnnotation` method:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function(){
        const chart = this;

        chart.addAnnotation({
            labels: [
              {
                point: {
                  x: 3,
                  y: chart.xAxis[0].max - 1,
                  xAxis: 0,
                  yAxis: 0
                },
                text: "x: {x}<br/>y: {y}"
              },
              {
                point: {
                  x: 0,
                  y: 0
                },
                text: "x: {point.plotX} px<br/>y: {point.plotY} px"
              },
              {
                point: {
                  x: 5,
                  y: 100,
                  xAxis: 0
                },
                text: "x: {x}<br/>y: {point.plotY} px"
              }
            ],
            labelOptions: {
              x: 40,
              y: -10
            }
         })
       }
     }
   }
```

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/537kz8xwyx